# Weird behavior of assertRaises (TestCase)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I've been trying/learning about unit testing works in Python and I came across this weird behavior, am I doing something wrong?

**Class**

```
class Entity:

    def __init__(self, n):
        if not isinstance(n, int):
            raise TypeError('n must be a number.')
        self.n = n
```

**Test**

```
from src.entity import Entity

class TestEntity(TestCase):

    def test__init__types(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, Entity.__init__, "2")
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, Entity.__init__, 2)
```

Shouldn't the test fail in the second `assertRaises` since 2 is a number thus the `TypeError` isn't raised? instead it says OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Entity.__init__(self, n)` takes *two* arguments: `self` and `n`. You're supplying only one, and getting a `TypeError`.

Observe:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, n):
...         print(n)
...         
>>> A.__init__('s')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

To test the constructor, you could do:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    Entity("2")
```

---

Now, *why* does this happen and where could one get that `self` argument from? The thing is that `__init__` is supplied with this argument automatically be `A.__new__`, so you could call `A.__new__` yourself, which would result in this weird looking code:

```
self.assertRaises(TypeError, A.__new__(A).__init__, "2")
```

Comment: How would I test a constructor then?

Comment: or keeping the call version: `self.assertRaises(TypeError, Entity, 2)`. The class itself is callable.

Comment: Thanks for the help.